# Sharing a blog in social media not displaying the correct count and not displaying image and description in codeigniter php

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I am having a blog page on my website there is an option to share the blog in social media like Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, and Google, but the problem is sharing the blog in social media not increasing the count for twitter and google. and unable to display the images and description while sharing the post on facebook.

Here is the code for that.

```
<p class="text41">
                            <div class="facebook2"><div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php echo base_url()?>blog/article/<?php echo $r ->blogtitle ;?>"data-layout="button_count"></div></div>
                            <div class="twitter2"><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-show-count="true">Tweet</a><script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script></div>
                            <div class="linkedin2"><span class="linkedincount"><script type="IN/Share" data-url="<?php echo base_url()?>blog/article/<?php echo $r ->blog_id ;?>" data-counter="right"></script></span></div>
                            <div class="google2"><div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-height="24" data-href="<?php echo base_url()?>blog/article/<?php echo $r ->blog_id ;?>"></div></div>  
                            </p>
```

Script For that

```
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Added meta tags in my header file:

```
<meta property="og:url"           content="www.yoursiteurl/page.com" />
<meta property="og:type"          content="Website name" />
<meta property="og:title"         content="Put the title here" />
<meta property="og:description"   content="Give a long description here" />
<meta property="og:image"         content="www.yoursite.com/urpicurl" />
```

But here how can i get the dynamic image and description from admin

Comment: You need to set up the correct meta tags so the services know what title/description/image you want. Here's an article about it: [Must-Have Social Meta Tags for Twitter, Google+, Facebook and More](https://moz.com/blog/meta-data-templates-123)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson my website is a dynamic website then how can i show the image and description of the blog clicking facebook share button.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i have updated my code

Comment: Each blog post should have their own info which you output using PHP. You could have the same info for all, like a generic info about the blog as a fall back. Exactly "how" you would do that is a bit broad since I don't know anything about your app.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i am sharing the blog in facebook need to show there respective image and description

Comment: So do as I suggested, have a share title, a share description and a share image on each blog post and just populate the meta data in the same way you populate the actual blog post.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson it is inserting from database how to give that name in meta tags

Comment: You have blog posts that you fetch from the database. Add three more columns in your table with posts: share_title, share_description and share_image. When you fetch a blog post from the database, you fetch those columns as well. Then you can just echo them in the correct place, just like you probably already are doing with the blog post content and title...

Comment: blog_id,image_path,blog_title,description these are the columns in my database so i need to add three more columns again